# MVVMCROSS Changing Language in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement a multilanguage support with mvvmcross in iOS. The "languages" are stored in a `.resx` file in the core (Portable Library Class).

So on the android side it works great......I have just to call the `recreathe()`-Method to rebuild the views.

Is there some similiar method I can call in iOS or in the MVVMCROSS-Library? I experimented a lot with several methods, but without any success.

I know how to make it manually:

- Remove all Subviews
- Create new instances for each removed subview
- Do the bindings again
- Add the views back to subviews

But honestly this just can't be the way it goes.
Has anyone a much more sleek suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your views use binding (like I described [here](http://enginecore.blogspot.ro/2013/09/localization-in-xamarin-mvvmcross_18.html) ) to display the localized version of the string values, the only thing you need to do is to call 
`RaisePropertyChanged(string.empty)` or `RaiseAllPropertiesChanged()` on the view-models

When user changes the language, you could broadcast a message (using MvmCross messenger) which all the language aware view-models listen to, and on handling this message have the view-models can then call `RaisePropertyChanged(string.empty)` or `RaiseAllPropertiesChanged()` on the view-models